# Is there a Pdf reader with regular expression search

Tags: software-recommendation, pdfgrep

When I want to search a snipet, like **searchPart1 some unknown  text searchPart2** in a text file, I use  `searchPart1.*searchPart2`. But this is not possible in any pdf reader I use. 
Currently I convert pdf to a text file and open it using `less` or `geany`, then use regular expression available on it.

Is there a Pdf reader with regular expression search other than the commandline `pdfgrep`

Comment: `pdfgrep` is a grepper so it didn't answer the question completely. A pdf reader with inbuilt pdfgrep is required to *accept* the answer

Answer (score 10):

**pdfgrep**, in the repos, isn't exactly a reader and requires use of the terminal but it eliminates the need to first convert the pdf file to a text file and then to open that in a capable text editor:

[image: pdfgrep]

In addition to the features listed in Synaptic, you can search multiple files and recursively. One big difference from regular `grep` is that pdfgrep doesn't provide line numbers but page numbers. `man pdfgrep` has details.

A simple example:

```
pdfgrep -in PATTERN FILENAME
```

Here, `i` is for case-insensitivity and `n` gives the page number, *not* line number.

An example of the output looks like:

[image: pdfgrep output]

There's a brief YouTube video, [Pdfgrep - Search Text Inside PDF Files - Linux CLI](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-fouhANZtnw) , as well.